# How to target specific letter/word with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

As a mere example, I want to apply the class "`fancy`" to **all occurrences** of the sign "`&amp;`" in the document.

The CSS:

```
.fancy { font-style: italic; }
```

So a text that looks like this:

```
Ben &amp; Jerry's
```

would be manipulated by jquery to this:

```
Ben <span class="fancy">&amp;</span> Jerry's
```

Is there a function to target specific words/phrases/letters like this?

Comment: In a case like this, is this running through a program which will correct the html entities first? & is often outputted as &amp;

Comment: i'm sorry, that's right, edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't something that jQuery is generally helpful with--it works more at the node level than the text/html level. However, [this might help](http://jsbin.com/ijufu3) ([source](http://jsbin.com/ijufu3/edit)):

```
$('p:contains(&)').each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace('&amp;','<span class=\'fancy\'>&amp;</span>')
  );
});
```

Obviously if you can restrict the initial search to something better than all paragraphs, it'd perform better. You should also test it to see if the `:contains` filter actually helps.

It's not pretty but it seems to work.

Comment: thank you very much for providing the example, I'm gonna try that now.

Comment: I think it will fail if you have something like: `<p>blah <a href="...&amp;...">...</a> blah blah</p>`. Maybe usage of `jQuery.text()` instead of `jQuery.html()` would be better idea? But I don't know whether `elementRef.tex("abc");` is even possible to use.

Answer (score 2):

There's a "highlight" plugin that does almost exactly what you describe:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

Regex is commonly used for this:

http://chirale.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/character-substitution-on-jquery/

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-select-specific-characters-and-replace-them