# Change font size of some characters in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to change the fontsize of some characters that get entered into a contenteditable div? I have seen similar questions posted about inserting html. Maybe I need to insert a span and set the css fontsize on it. Or is there an alternative way?

Comment: No, there's not an alternative way, except a span can be some other element too.

Comment: find and replace?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530294/8157693

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out a solution, see: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/6o1sr5fg/

- If there are text that needs highlighting, first we just copy over
  the content HTML to div.readonly for further processing. If no
  highlighting is required, we just empty the div.
- The    `collectTextNodes()` function iterates through all the DOM nodes
  in the    content HTML, and collects all text nodes. The collected
  nodes would    only contain text, and no child nodes.
- For all the text nodes we    collected, we run them through the
  `highlight()` function to highlight    the text.
- highlight() works by first skipping maximumLength number of
  characters, then wrap everything in `<span class='highlight'>.`